# How to append 0 and 1 to different classes of images / deep learning

Tags: python

I am a beginner in python and deep learning language, I am creating my list of `X_train` composed of two different classes of images and I would like to assign 0s and 1s to each class.

So let's say

```
X_train=[]
Y_train=[]
X_train.append(imageA)
X_train.append(imageB)
```

So I would like to assign 0s and 1s to the image classes in my Y_train list
I share with you these two lines of code which summarize my reasoning and which are obviously false since I am here looking for solutions

```
for i, imageA in enumerate (X_train):
    Y_train.append(1)

for j, imageB in enumerate (X_train):
    Y_train.append(0)
```

What is the correct way to do this?
Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Hey Meriem, could you be clearer about what you are trying to achieve (git an example of the desired output )?

Comment: No, I want to know the right way to append1 for imageA and 0 for imageB knowing that both image classes are in the X_train list
the code i wrote at the end is wrong but thats what i would like to do someway

Comment: ok, I think I understand, but could you just clarify how the class of  `imageA` and `imageB` looks? (copy the definition of the class to the post or to a comment ...), since otherwise i don't really know how to ass 0 or 1 to that class

Comment: I'm doing a binary classification of skin lesion it's way too long to explain everything lol
but let's say I want to assign class 1 for all images imageA and 0 for all images imageb  that both are in X_train list

Comment: @MeriemChahinezBen, here you have not mentioned how we identify imageA and imageB but if you have a way to do so you could use below code - 

X_train=[]
Y_train=[]

for img in X_train:
    if img == imageA:
        Y_train.append(1)
    elif img == imageB:
        Y_train.append(0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way at the end of the code `Y_train` will include two lists,
the first one is of all the images of type `imageB` and the second one of all the images of the type `imageA`

I wasn't sure how you meant to identify which image is witch so I used `is` but feel free to replace it with any way you want

```
zero_lst = []
one_lst = []

for img in X_train:
    if img is imageA:
        one_lst.append(img)

for img in X_train:
    if img is imageB:
        zero_lst.append(img)

Y_train = [zero_lst, one_lst]
```

If my comment helped you please consider marking it as the answer :)